# React Native Post Requests

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am currently trying to make a simple post request to google sheets using the googlesheetsAPI. I am easily able to make a get request but can't seem to get a post to work. Ive followed instructions for multiple different sources but nothing seems to work. Here is my code currently:

'''

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {


  async componentDidMount() {

    try{

      await fetch('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1586I9OO1aTT5OFG9igtuo-VTYUNI-Ec-SqyHfDSXdgo/values/sheet1?valueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE&key=AIzaSyCx2qnVLidzHy9v2I76_xyLhDtyUxqc2Ls', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          value: '1',
        })
      });

    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

  }
  render(){
    return (
      <View></View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

'''

Comment: looks like issue is with your API

Comment: You'r **method: 'post'** should be the **method: 'POST'** . Word post should be Capital.

Comment: I tried it using 'POST' initially but that doesnt seem to be the cause of the problem

Comment: I've checked with another API, its working with other post api. 
You've issue with your API URL.

Comment: @Kailash Do you know how I would format the URL if making a post request to google sheets?

Comment: Unfortunately, API key cannot be used for the method except for GET method while API key can be used for GET method. In your situation, it is required to use the access token. And also, if you want to use ["Method: spreadsheets.values.update"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update), PUT method is required to be used. Also, this method has no query parameter of `valueRenderOption`. Please be careful about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are some things to be aware when consuming Google APIs without the usage of a client package.

- Some endpoints don't require you to go through the full `OAuth flow`, others do. That depends from case to case, but in general if you are fetching sensitive information or modifying data via API, going through the generating access tokens are very likely to be required.
- You must have a Cloud console project instance with your `API key` and `OAuth credentials` previously configured since you will need that information to actually consume the API.
- Always read the desired API endpoint documentation. Different endpoints (within the same API) might expect different information to be included in the request. In your example, and crediting `@Tanaike` to pointing that out in the comments, the `spreadsheets.values.update` expects a `PUT` method and a `Bearer` header (populated with you access token retrieved from the OAuth authentication flow) in your request. Note that you'll still need the your `API key` to be included in the requested URL. Also, the first parameter after `/values/` in your URL expects a A1 notation for the range you'd like to update and the request body expects an object with [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange) format. See the full documentation for this method [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) and some example of implementations (using clients) [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)
- So here is the info you'll need to change on your code:

```
_____URL_&_PARAMETERS_____
method: 'PUT'
URL: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[spreadsheetId]/values/[rangeA1Notation]?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]'

_____REQUEST_HEADERS_____
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

_______REQUEST_BODY_______
{
  "values": [
    [
      "YOUR_NEW_VALUE_HERE"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps, Cheers!