# Edit Google sheet with API react-native

Tags: react-native, post, axios, google-sheets-api

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export async function addRowToGoogleSheets(data) {
  const formattedData = {
    values: [data],
  };

  // Define the API request URL
  const apiRequestURL = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{ID-SHEET}/values/users?valueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE&key={KEY}";

  try {
    console.log("Formatted Data:", formattedData);
    console.log("API Request URL:", apiRequestURL);

    await axios.post(apiRequestURL, formattedData);

    return true; // Indicate success
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error adding row:', error);
    throw error; // Re-throw the error to be caught by the caller
  }
}
```

React-native
I have a Google Sheet document that I want to update in my application - adding a line with more values that are accepted.
I opened the document permissions for editing, enabled the corresponding API and entered the key.

I can only do GET.

When I try to POST I get a 404 error.

I could not find a solution or reason.
I would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Dupicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73972330/12163469